# spring integration - read a remote file line by line

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to read a remote file line by line, using spring integration. Using the spring documentation found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html) I have set up my project to poll for the file and transfer it via sftp when it is found. I am stuck on how to go about reading the file contents one line at a time.

Here is my inbound channel adapter setup that currently works to pull in files.

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        channel="receiveChannel"
        filename-pattern="*.txt"
        remote-directory="/home/springftp"
        preserve-timestamp="true"
        local-directory="file:C:\sprintftp"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
        delete-remote-files="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel"> 
    <int:queue/> 
</int:channel>
```

Edit: To clarify, I would like to retrieve one line at a time from the remote file, then process the contents of that line, then retrieve the next line. Similar to creating a java.io.inputstream for a local file and reading it line by line.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<file-to-string-transformer>` after the receiving File and `<splitter>` to delimit the content of `payload` to the list of lines.

**UPDATE**

> I would like to retrieve one line at a time from the remote file, then process the contents of that line, then retrieve the next line. Similar to creating a java.io.inputstream for a local file and reading it line by line.

Well, Unfortunatelly we don't provide high-level component for that, but you can try to use the features from the `RemoteFileTemplate`:

```
RemoteFileTemplate<FTPFile> template = new RemoteFileTemplate<FTPFile>(this.ftpSessionFactory);
template.setFileNameExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("payload"));
template.setBeanFactory(mock(BeanFactory.class));
template.afterPropertiesSet();
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
template.get(new GenericMessage<String>("ftpSource/ftpSource1.txt"), new InputStreamCallback() {

    @Override
    public void doWithInputStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        FileCopyUtils.copy(stream, baos1);
    }
});
```

This code you can to some your POJO service and wire the last one with `<service-activator>`.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify my intentions. I would like to retrieve one  line at a time from the remote file, then process the contents of that line, then retrieve the next line. Similar to creating a java.io.inputstream for a local file and reading it line by line.

Comment: @ArtemBilan can't we use SFTP outbound gateway `get` command with `-stream` option to read the file as stream? http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway