# Read CSV file concurrently using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to process CSV file concurrently using spring integration. Each row will be converted into individual message. So Assuming I am having 10K rows in CSV file , I would like to start 10 Thread , each row will be pass to this Thread. it would be great if anyone show me any sample example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [Spring Integration 4.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whats-new.html#4.1-splitter-iterator) the `<splitter>` supports `Iterator` as `payload` to split. Hence you can convert inbound `File` to the `LineIterator` and process messages for each line in paralle, if an `output-channel` of `<splitter>` is `ExecutorChannel`:

```
<splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="executorChannel"
          expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about prior to 4.0 ? I am afraid I can migrate to Spring 4.0!. I am fine even it read  first full file and creating messages for multiple threads to handle.

Comment: Well, consider to use `FlatFileItemReader`(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.java) from Spring Batch (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#flatFiles)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring Integration 4.1.0 and have tried your suggestion however it doesn't seem to be working for me.
I've gotten to look into this a bit today and now lean toward it being a Spring Integration 4.1.0 bug.

See if what I explain makes sense.

If you try this example, you'll see it will work (note this is NOT using your SpEL example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file" xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="exchangeReplayFileAdapter" ref="exchangeReplayFileReadingMessageSource" method="receive" auto-startup="true" channel="channel1">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="10000000" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="exchangeReplayFileReadingMessageSource" class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource">
        <property name="directory" value="/tmp/inputdir" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
    </int:channel>

    <int:splitter input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2">
        <bean class="com.xxx.common.util.springintegration.FileSplitter" />
    </int:splitter>

    <int:channel id="channel2"></int:channel>
    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter channel="channel2"></int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
</beans>
```

With this `Splitter` implementation...

```
package com.xxx.common.util.springintegration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class FileSplitter extends AbstractMessageSplitter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileSplitterNew.class);

    public Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(message.toString());
        }
        try {

            Object payload = message.getPayload();
            Assert.isInstanceOf(File.class, payload, "Expected java.io.File in the message payload");
            return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.lineIterator((File) payload);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "Unable to transform file: " + e.getMessage();
            log.error(msg);
            throw new MessageTransformationException(msg, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Using your SpEL example:

```
<int:splitter input-channel="exchangeReplayFiles" output-channel="exchangeSpringQueueChannel"  
    expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)"/>
```

what internally gets created by the parser is this (notice the `List.class` type passed into the `ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor` constructor:

```
/**
 * A Message Splitter implementation that evaluates the specified SpEL
 * expression. The result of evaluation will typically be a Collection or
 * Array. If the result is not a Collection or Array, then the single Object
 * will be returned as the payload of a single reply Message.
 *
 * @author Mark Fisher
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter extends AbstractMessageProcessingSplitter {

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter(Expression expression) {
        super(new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor(expression, List.class));
    }

}
```

And the `ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor` class:

```
/**
 * A {@link MessageProcessor} implementation that evaluates a SpEL expression
 * with the Message itself as the root object within the evaluation context.
 *
 * @author Mark Fisher
 * @author Artem Bilan
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor<T> extends AbstractMessageProcessor<T> {

    private final Expression expression;

    private final Class<T> expectedType;


  ...
    /**
     * Create an {@link ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor} for the given expression
     * and expected type for its evaluation result.
     * @param expression The expression.
     * @param expectedType The expected type.
     */
    public ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor(Expression expression, Class<T> expectedType) {
        Assert.notNull(expression, "The expression must not be null");
        try {
            this.expression = expression;
            this.expectedType = expectedType;
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse expression.", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processes the Message by evaluating the expression with that Message as the
     * root object. The expression evaluation result Object will be returned.
     * @param message The message.
     * @return The result of processing the message.
     */
    @Override
    public T processMessage(Message<?> message) {
        return this.evaluateExpression(this.expression, message, this.expectedType);
    }
...

}
```

What gets returned from the sample provided ends up being an `ArrayList` (which implements the `Collection` interface) containing a single `LineIterator` element.

The `ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter` is a subclass of `AbstractMessageSplitter` and it does NOT override the `handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message)` method.
That method looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageSplitter extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {
    protected final Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message) {
        Object result = this.splitMessage(message);
        // return null if 'null'
        if (result == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Iterator<Object> iterator;
        final int sequenceSize;
        if (result instanceof Collection) {
            Collection<Object> items = (Collection<Object>) result;
            sequenceSize = items.size();
            iterator = items.iterator();
        }
        else if (result.getClass().isArray()) {
            Object[] items = (Object[]) result;
            sequenceSize = items.length;
            iterator = Arrays.asList(items).iterator();
        }
        else if (result instanceof Iterable<?>) {
            sequenceSize = 0;
            iterator = ((Iterable<Object>) result).iterator();
        }
        else if (result instanceof Iterator<?>) {
            sequenceSize = 0;
            iterator = (Iterator<Object>) result;
        }
        else {
            sequenceSize = 1;
            iterator = Collections.singleton(result).iterator();
        }

        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }

        final MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        final Object correlationId = headers.getId();
        final AtomicInteger sequenceNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);

        return new FunctionIterator<Object, AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>>(iterator,
                new Function<Object, AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> apply(Object object) {
                        return createBuilder(object, headers, correlationId, sequenceNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                                sequenceSize);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Since `ArrayList` is indeed a `Collection`, it never gets to the logic where it sets the iterator, and therefore never calls the `next()` on the iterator in the `produceOutput(...)` method.

So why is `LineIterator` cohearsed into an `ArrayList`?  I believe there is a flaw in the `ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter` in that it always does this:

```
public ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter(Expression expression) {
    super(new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor(expression, List.class));
}
```

I think in Spring Integration 4 it should now look at the type the expression evaluates to (either a `List` or an `Iterator`) then call the super (might need to rework how that is done since deciding type would be done before calling the super which JVM won't allow).

What do you think?