# FileWritingMessageHandler (int-file:outbound-channel-adapter) is slow for single-file storing multiple-messages use case

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, log4j2, spring-el

I'm using Spring 4.1.2 with Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a use case where I'd like to produce a single file that will contain a row for each message that flowed to a channel.  Messages received are all of type `String`.  This file is a nice-to-have file, meaning it's not necessary to have the writing to this file be within the same transaction of the master flow.  So an async wire-tap pattern could be implemented for the use-case.  Any messages written to that file however need to be in the same order that they originally were received in (so either 1 thread would need to process them or would need an aggregator to wait for multiple threads to complete then would write them in the original order).

I wanted to get a feel for what would be the most performant way to handle this use-case so I tried a few tests.  To make it a bit easier my tests are not using an async wire-tap (but this was mentioned in the use-case because perhaps some suggestions might involve batching/buffering solutions).

The general flow came from the "Define an integration flow" section of this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/

The main options I tried were:

1. Use `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` (which creates a `FileWritingMessageHandler`) along with a transformer that appends a newline to each message (transformer uses SpEL expression `payload + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}`.
   `spring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF`
2. Use `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` (which creates a `FileWritingMessageHandler`) along with a transformer that appends a newline to each message (transformer uses SpEL expression `payload.toString() + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}`.
   `spring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED`
   **NOTE:** Using `payload.toString()` rather than `payload` to get around SpEL issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12514
3. Use `int:logging-channel-adapter` rather than `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` (saving on having to use a transformer with a SpEL expression).
   Tested with Log4J2 using `RollingRandomAccessFile` and synchronous loggers.
   `spring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF`
4. Use `int:logging-channel-adapter` rather than `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` (saving on having to use a transformer with a SpEL expression).
   Tested with Log4J2 using `RollingRandomAccessFile` and asynchronous loggers. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/async.html#Making All Loggers Asynchronous .
   `spring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF`
5. Use `int:logging-channel-adapter` rather than `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` (saving on having to use a transformer with a SpEL expression).
   Tested with Log4J2 using `RollingRandomAccessFile` and asynchronous loggers. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/async.html#Making All Loggers Asynchronous .
   `spring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED`

Test cases 1 and 2 flow:
[image: int-file:outbound-channel-adapter flow]

Test cases 3 thru 5 flow:
[image: int:logging-channel-adapter flow]

The input file contains XML data (strings) that vary in length between 1200 and 1500 chars per line (each line is a single message).
In my test I have 203,712 messages.
Below are the timings.  I'm showing the timings for the first items a bit more than the last items since the SpEL compiler kicks in after a certain period of time.

```
|          1              |            2             |              3                 |               4                |              5                 |
|SpringInt FileAdapter    | SpringInt FileAdapter    | Log4j2 RollingRandomAccessFile | Log4j2 RollingRandomAccessFile | Log4j2 RollingRandomAccessFile |
|                         |                          | Sync Loggers                   | Async Loggers                  | Async with                     |
|SpEL-compiler=OFF        | SpEL-compiler=MIXED      | SpEL-compiler=OFF              | SpEL-compiler=OFF              | SpEL-compiler=MIXED            |
|-------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|------------------------------- |
|Cnt=10000 : 0:00:12.670  | Cnt=10000 : 0:00:17.235  | Cnt=10000 : 0:00:08.222        | Cnt=10000 : 0:00:01.847        | Cnt=10000 : 0:00:01.320        |
|Cnt=20000 : 0:00:24.636  | Cnt=20000 : 0:00:30.208  | Cnt=20000 : 0:00:08.828        | Cnt=20000 : 0:00:02.232        | Cnt=20000 : 0:00:01.839        |
|Cnt=30000 : 0:00:36.179  | Cnt=30000 : 0:00:44.300  | Cnt=30000 : 0:00:09.426        | Cnt=30000 : 0:00:02.512        | Cnt=30000 : 0:00:02.647        |
|...                      | ....                     | ...                            | ...                            | ...                            |
|Cnt=180000 : 0:02:58.935 | Cnt=180000 : 0:04:15.528 | Cnt=180000 : 0:00:17.095       | Cnt=180000 : 0:00:08.546       | Cnt=180000 : 0:00:07.936       |
|Cnt=200000 : 0:03:16.473 | Cnt=200000 : 0:04:35.582 | Cnt=200000 : 0:00:18.107       | Cnt=200000 : 0:00:09.548       | Cnt=200000 : 0:00:08.660       |
|Cnt=203712 : 0:03:19.715 | Cnt=203712 : 0:04:39.452 | Cnt=203712 : 0:00:18.284       | Cnt=203712 : 0:00:09.661       | Cnt=203712 : 0:00:08.732       |
```

Take the timings with a grain of salt - I didn't run these dozens of times and take averages.  I'm also not advocating that log4j2 is faster than other offerrings like logback, I'm merely using it for comparision purposes.  NOTE:  I'm using a file as input just for this test.  I point that out because someone might suggest to just have Spring Integration copy the raw file from fileA to fileB.  In our real use-case however the messages actually come in via JMS so the file-to-file solution is not a real option.
Interesting points:

- Spring Integration `FileWritingMessageHandler` is MUCH slower than any log4j2 offering.
  **Log4j2-async took 4.3% of time `FileWritingMessageHandler` did (199.715 secs for scenario1 vs 8.732 sec for scenario5).**
  **Log4j2-sync took 4.8% of time `FileWritingMessageHandler` did (199.715 secs for scenario1 vs 9.661 sec for scenario4).**
- Spring Integration `FileWritingMessageHandler` with `spring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED` (scenario #2) is actually slower than `spring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF`.  I assume it's because in scenario #1 I was able to use `payload + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}` whereas in scenario #2 I had to use `payload.toString() + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}`
- Scenarios 3 thru 5 are as expected, relative to the other scenarios.

Ideally I don't like having to use the `logging-channel-adapter` just to write messages into a file - seems like I'm bastardizing that component.  The performance gain however is signficant so unfortunately as of now I can't rule out using that.
So my questions are:

- What other options do I have besides writing my own `FileWritingMessageHandler` to get better file-writing performance?
- I assume perhaps if I batch or aggregate prior to the `FileWritingMessageHandler` then write out the batched group performance might be better.  I'm sure I could also use a task-executor and a poller (my use-case would permit this).  If batching should be considered as an option should the `FileWritingMessageHandler` expose a `buffersize` attribute?
- Could the `FileWritingMessageHandler` be tweaked, or perhaps could additional more-specific versions be offerred that would be more performant for my use-case (perhaps taking some advice/hints from the log4j2 loggers)?
- Would a file `StreamWriter` be more performant?
- Just thinking out-loud on this one:  Should a log4j2 "wrapper" class that acts purely as a file-adapter be offerred (i.e. it would have to only log the message with no line/class/etc info, would always have to write regardless of level, user would merely pass in a filename and perhaps sync/async)?
- Can the SpEL compiler be better optimized to handle the `payload.toString() + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}` case, since as noted it was actually slower than not calling the toString() in SpEL itself?

Below is the code/config files used for the tests.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Testing -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Integration -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Binding for JCL (aka Java Common Logging).  -->
        <!-- Needed since things like the commons libs all use commons-logging which we don't want -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <!-- Making scope be runtime so we'll catch any of our own classes that try to use commons-logging when we compile -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Binding for Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <!-- As of 9/12/2014 our company Maven repos does not have 2.0.2 -->
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j API and Core implementation required for binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Async loggers for log4j2 require LMAX disruptor, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Java classes**

```
package com.xxx;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * Starts the Spring Context and will initialize the Spring Integration routes.
 */
public final class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    private Main() {
    }

    /**
     * Load the Spring Integration Application Context
     *
     * @param args - command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String... args) {

        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("\n=========================================================" + "\n                                                         " + "\n          Welcome to Spring Integration!                 " + "\n                                                         " + "\n    For more information please visit:                   " + "\n    http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration       " + "\n                                                         " + "\n=========================================================");
        }

        final AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context-usecases.xml");

        context.registerShutdownHook();

        SpringIntegrationUtils.displayDirectories(context);

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("\n=========================================================" + "\n                                                         " + "\n    Please press 'q + Enter' to quit the application.    " + "\n                                                         " + "\n=========================================================");
        }

        while (!scanner.hasNext("q")) {
            //Do nothing unless user presses 'q' to quit.
        }

        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("Exiting application...bye.");
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }
}



package com.xxx;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.integration.routingslip.RoutingSlipRouteStrategy;
import org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter;
import org.springframework.integration.support.AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;
import org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * This class is only needed until a bug is fixed in Spring Integration 4.1.0.
 * See {@link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171978/read-csv-file-concurrently-using-spring-integration}
 * Once that is fixed delete this class and use this in the Spring context file.
 * <code>
 * <splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="executorChannel" expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)"/>
 * </code>
 *
 */
public class FileSplitter extends AbstractMessageSplitter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileSplitter.class);

    int counter = 0;
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

    public Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(message.toString());
        }
        try {

            Object payload = message.getPayload();
            Assert.isInstanceOf(File.class, payload, "Expected java.io.File in the message payload");

            return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.lineIterator((File) payload);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "Unable to transform file: " + e.getMessage();
            log.error(msg);
            throw new MessageTransformationException(msg, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void produceOutput(Object result, Message<?> requestMessage) {

        Iterator<?> iterator = (Iterator<?>) result;
        sw.start();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ++counter;
            produceOutputInternal(iterator.next(), requestMessage);
            if (counter % 10000 == 0) {
                sw.split();
                System.out.println("Cnt=" + counter + " : " + sw.toSplitString());
            }
        }
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println("completed");
        System.out.println("Cnt=" + counter + " : " + sw.toSplitString());
    }

    private Object getOutputChannelFromRoutingSlip(Object reply, Message<?> requestMessage, List<?> routingSlip, AtomicInteger routingSlipIndex) {
        if (routingSlipIndex.get() >= routingSlip.size()) {
            return null;
        }

        Object path = routingSlip.get(routingSlipIndex.get());
        Object routingSlipPathValue = null;

        if (path instanceof String) {
            routingSlipPathValue = getBeanFactory().getBean((String) path);
        } else if (path instanceof RoutingSlipRouteStrategy) {
            routingSlipPathValue = path;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The RoutingSlip 'path' can be of " + "String or RoutingSlipRouteStrategy type, but gotten: " + path);
        }

        if (routingSlipPathValue instanceof MessageChannel) {
            routingSlipIndex.incrementAndGet();
            return routingSlipPathValue;
        } else {
            Object nextPath = ((RoutingSlipRouteStrategy) routingSlipPathValue).getNextPath(requestMessage, reply);
            if (nextPath != null && (!(nextPath instanceof String) || StringUtils.hasText((String) nextPath))) {
                return nextPath;
            } else {
                routingSlipIndex.incrementAndGet();
                return getOutputChannelFromRoutingSlip(reply, requestMessage, routingSlip, routingSlipIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void produceOutputInternal(Object reply, Message<?> requestMessage) {
        MessageHeaders requestHeaders = requestMessage.getHeaders();

        Object replyChannel = null;
        if (getOutputChannel() == null) {
            Map<?, ?> routingSlipHeader = requestHeaders.get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP, Map.class);
            if (routingSlipHeader != null) {
                Assert.isTrue(routingSlipHeader.size() == 1, "The RoutingSlip header value must be a SingletonMap");
                Object key = routingSlipHeader.keySet().iterator().next();
                Object value = routingSlipHeader.values().iterator().next();
                Assert.isInstanceOf(List.class, key, "The RoutingSlip key must be List");
                Assert.isInstanceOf(Integer.class, value, "The RoutingSlip value must be Integer");
                List<?> routingSlip = (List<?>) key;
                AtomicInteger routingSlipIndex = new AtomicInteger((Integer) value);
                replyChannel = getOutputChannelFromRoutingSlip(reply, requestMessage, routingSlip, routingSlipIndex);
                if (replyChannel != null) {
                    //TODO Migrate to the SF MessageBuilder
                    AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> builder = null;
                    if (reply instanceof Message) {
                        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) reply);
                    } else if (reply instanceof AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder) {
                        builder = (AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>) reply;
                    } else {
                        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(reply);
                    }
                    builder.setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP, Collections.singletonMap(routingSlip, routingSlipIndex.get()));
                    reply = builder;
                }
            }

            if (replyChannel == null) {
                replyChannel = requestHeaders.getReplyChannel();
            }
        }

        Message<?> replyMessage = createOutputMessage(reply, requestHeaders);
        sendOutput(replyMessage, replyChannel);
    }

    private Message<?> createOutputMessage(Object output, MessageHeaders requestHeaders) {
        AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> builder = null;
        if (output instanceof Message<?>) {
            if (!this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
                return (Message<?>) output;
            }
            builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) output);
        } else if (output instanceof AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder) {
            builder = (AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>) output;
        } else {
            builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(output);
        }
        if (this.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()) {
            builder.copyHeadersIfAbsent(requestHeaders);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private void sendOutput(Object output, Object replyChannel) {
        MessageChannel outputChannel = getOutputChannel();
        if (outputChannel != null) {
            replyChannel = outputChannel;
        }
        if (replyChannel == null) {
            throw new DestinationResolutionException("no output-channel or replyChannel header available");
        }

        if (replyChannel instanceof MessageChannel) {
            if (output instanceof Message<?>) {
                this.messagingTemplate.send((MessageChannel) replyChannel, (Message<?>) output);
            } else {
                this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend((MessageChannel) replyChannel, output);
            }
        } else if (replyChannel instanceof String) {
            if (output instanceof Message<?>) {
                this.messagingTemplate.send((String) replyChannel, (Message<?>) output);
            } else {
                this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend((String) replyChannel, output);
            }
        } else {
            throw new MessagingException("replyChannel must be a MessageChannel or String");
        }
    }
}


package com.xxx;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.DirectFieldAccessor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;

/**
 * Displays the names of the input and output directories.
 */
public final class SpringIntegrationUtils {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SpringIntegrationUtils.class);

    private SpringIntegrationUtils() { }

    /**
     * Helper Method to dynamically determine and display input and output
     * directories as defined in the Spring Integration context.
     *
     * @param context Spring Application Context
     */
    public static void displayDirectories(final ApplicationContext context) {

        final File inDir = (File) new DirectFieldAccessor(context.getBean(FileReadingMessageSource.class)).getPropertyValue("directory");

        final Map<String, FileWritingMessageHandler> fileWritingMessageHandlers = context.getBeansOfType(FileWritingMessageHandler.class);

        final List<String> outputDirectories = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (final FileWritingMessageHandler messageHandler : fileWritingMessageHandlers.values()) {
            final Expression outDir = (Expression) new DirectFieldAccessor(messageHandler).getPropertyValue("destinationDirectoryExpression");
            outputDirectories.add(outDir.getExpressionString());
        }

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append("\n=========================================================");
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("\n    Input directory is : '" + inDir.getAbsolutePath() + "'");

        for (final String outputDirectory : outputDirectories) {
            stringBuilder.append("\n    Output directory is: '" + outputDirectory + "'");
        }

        stringBuilder.append("\n\n=========================================================");

        logger.info(stringBuilder.toString());

    }

}
```

**`log4j2.xml` config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%t] [%-5p] (%c) - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="fileAppenderMessages" fileName="C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/fileadapter-test/usecase3.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m %n" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- The Wire-Tap and logging-channel-adapter in the Spring cfg file will use this category name -->
        <Logger name="fileLogger" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileAppenderMessages" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**`spring-integration-context-usecases.xml` file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileAdapter" ref="fileReadingMessageSource" method="receive" auto-startup="true" channel="files" >
        <int:poller fixed-delay="#{T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="fileReadingMessageSource" class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource">
        <property name="directory" value="C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/tmg-exchange-gateway-nam/t2"/>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="files"/>

    <int:splitter input-channel="files" output-channel="stringMessages">
        <bean class="com.xxx.FileSplitter" />
    </int:splitter>

    <int:channel id="stringMessages"/>

    <int:transformer expression="payload + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'" output-channel="file" auto-startup="true" input-channel="stringMessages"/>
    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file"
            mode="APPEND"
            charset="UTF-8"
            directory="C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/fileadapter-test"
            auto-create-directory="true"
            filename-generator-expression="'usecase2.txt'"/>
</beans>
```

Tests can be run using these settings:

```
1. java -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF com.xxx.Main
Leave context file unchanged.
2. java -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED com.xxx.Main
Change context file to have expression="payload.toString() + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
3. java -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF com.xxx.Main
Comment out transformer and outbound-channel-adapter.
Change logging-channel-adapter   auto-startup="true"
4. java -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector  -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=OFF com.xxx.Main
Comment out transformer and outbound-channel-adapter.
Change logging-channel-adapter   auto-startup="true"
5. java -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector  -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED com.xxx.Main
Comment out transformer and outbound-channel-adapter.
Change logging-channel-adapter   auto-startup="true"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the extensive analysis.

To be honest, the `APPEND` mode is a relatively recent addition to the outbound adapter and has not been optimized.

I suspect the cost is simply because the stream is closed on each write (using `FileCopy.copy()`) which flushes to disk.

We should definitely consider an option to keep the `BufferedOutputStream` open. It's a little tricky because the adapter supports writing to a different file for each message. I presume your use case is you always write to the same file, or some timestamp-based file name. We could provide some optimization to keep the file open until a request for a different file comes in, or even keep several file buffers open.

At some, point, though, we would want to flush the buffer(s) if no new messages arrive after some time elapses. This adds some complexity (but not a lot).

Of course, the downside is that there is a risk of data loss in the event of a power failure when you have data buffered in memory. This is a classic tradeoff - performance Vs. reliability; right now this adapter errs towards the latter.

As always, feel free to open up a JIRA issue and we'll take a look.

Comment: Yes your presumption is correct, we always write to the same file for a section of our flow (many messages to same file).  We understand the risk of data-loss using a buffered-file and as-such we don't rely on these files for things other then reporting or UAT data-sync type purposes.  See JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3574