# Use SFTP Outbound Gateway to Obtain Input Stream

Tags: spring-integration

I am attempting to process a file exactly like this question:
[read a remote file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934275/spring-integration-read-a-remote-file-line-by-line)

The one answer to this question suggests to use RemoteFileTemplate but I am
attempting to use the -stream option as suggested in the last comment to the
answer.  Also, this kinda seems like the point of the -stream option; to get a stream.

My implementation successfully obtains the InputStream and kick off a separate thread to
process in a BufferedReader.

This works happily on windows laptop but deployment on a linux machine I
sometimes get a "Write end dead" exception caught when trying to read the
BufferedReader in my processing thread.

Research into this suggests the writer is not closing the stream properly:
[Write end dead exception using PipedInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453525/write-end-dead-exception-using-pipedinputstream-java)

So, either this is a bug in spring-integration or there is something missing
in my configuration.  I am hoping it is the latter and could use feedback on
the way I am obtaining the InputStream.  If I am getting the InputStream
correctly, then how can I get the writer to close the input stream after writing?

Thanks!

Here is outbound gateway configuration:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    request-channel="inboundGetStream" command="get" command-options="-stream"
    expression="payload" remote-directory="/" reply-channel="stream">
</int-ftp:outbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="stream">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

Here is where I obtain the InputStream:

```
public InputStream openFileStream(final String filename, final String directory) throws Exception {
    if (inboundGetStream.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(directory + "/" + filename).build(), ftpTimeout)) {
        return getInputStream();
    }
    return null;
}

private InputStream getInputStream() {

    Message<?> msgs = stream.receive(ftpTimeout);

    if (msgs == null) {
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is = (InputStream) msgs.getPayload();
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better if you share more StackTrace to investigate.

Plus, I don't see that you close the session as it is recommended by the solution:

> When consuming remote files as streams, the user is responsible for closing the Session after the stream is consumed. For convenience, the `Session` is provided in the `file_remoteSession` header.

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="markers"
           expression="payload.mark.toString().equals('END') ? headers['file_remoteSession'].close() : null"/>
```

As a sample from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway).

On the other hand it would be better to consume the `InputStream` in the same thread as it has been obtained. Not shifting such a low level, session tied resource to the Queue.

Also check, please, this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359184 . Maybe you really should upgrade to something more fresh: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.jcraft%22

Comment: Brilliant insight and super thanks for such quick answer!  Not closing the session seems to be the problem.  I had saw that in the reference manual but for some reason thought it only applied when using the splitter but after reading again I see my original misunderstanding.  My exact solution for my config:
`<int:service-activator input-channel="stream"
           expression="payload.toString().equals('END') ? headers['file_remoteSession'].close() : null"/>`

Comment: I have follow up question somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798170/no-messages-when-obtaining-input-stream-from-sftp-outbound-gateway